# How to downgrade Node.js from version 16 LTS to 14 LTS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project that requires downgrading Node.js. I'm currently using Node.js version 16 and my project should be using Node.js version 14. Does anyone know how to downgrade Node.js version without conflicts and errors? Thank you. I am use Windows

Comment: Which platform are you working on? Windows? or Linux?

Comment: You can use nvm

Answer (score 0):

For windows:

Steps

1. Go to > Control panel> program and features>Node.js then uninstall
2. Go to website: https://nodejs.org/en/ and download the version and install.